# Android: Unable to make a location request dialog and get the location on callback

Tags: java, android, location

I have followed the official documentation from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings) to display the location dialog to the user as our app doesn't work without location. The problem is that even when I press the OK button on the dialog, sometimes the onFailure of the task listener gets called, more importantly, even when onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) does get called, I'm unable to immediately get the location details, the workaround I made is to create a separate thread to get the details in a loop. I need to know a simpler method to do this.

This took me over 2 days time and I still can't figure what's wrong in my code.

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client;
TextView textView;
boolean started = false;
double lat = 0;
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e(tag, "no perm");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else
        work();
}

void work() {
    if (!isLocationEnabled()) createLocationRequest();
    else locationDetails();
}

int t = 0;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e(tag, "activity result");
    work();
}

void locationDetails() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    client.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        if(lat!=0)return;
                        lat = location.getLatitude();
                        textView.setText("location: lat" + lat + " lng" + location.getLongitude());
                        Log.e(tag, "happy");
                    } else {
                        repeatedRequests();
                        Log.e(tag, "null location");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else work();
}

void createLocationRequest() {
    final LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    final SettingsClient settingsclient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsclient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            repeatedRequests();
            Log.e(tag, "success");
        }
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                Log.e(tag, "failure" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            //    repeatedRequests();
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                    Log.e(tag, "erorr " + sendEx.getLocalizedMessage());
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

void repeatedRequests() {
    if (!started) {
        started = true;
        Log.e(tag, "Thread started");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (lat == 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    t++;
                    if (t > 50) break;
                    Log.e(tag, "repeat");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            locationDetails();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    int locationMode = 0;

    try {
        locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
}
```

Comment: OnFailureListener() gets triggered even when no button is pressed.

Comment: Hi, when you try to make `ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                            2); ` you get answer on onActivityResult. The click on system dialog will be there. show yours `onActivityResult`, also on what device/os version you check it?

Comment: I've checked it on Samsung S8, which runs on API 26

Comment: I have received the result, but still, I needed to call the loop to get the location requests. I can't know for sure when the location is  guarenteed to be retrieved.

Comment: )))))) take it easy. It's BUG on samsung s8 and note. I'd checked it on 3 devices of samsung s8. there are one thing what you can do - when you catch `onActivityResult requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED` you can show dialog second time and if user click ok you will get location in yours LocationRequest.

Comment: try to check in settings of s8, when you click ok on dialog it will start location service but with settings low using battery, if you change settings to high this also will give location.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);`
just for yours samsung, in my case it works but keep in the mind that `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` will return false in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> getLastLocation()

it works when there is at least one subscriber to the google service..

You need to subscribe, and if you do not need to constantly update the coordinates, you can immediately unsubscribe...

```
    val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
            val location = locationResult?.lastLocation
            //job.invoke()
            client.removeLocationUpdates(this)
        }
    }, Looper.myLooper())
```